# Payment method not working in magento 2.4.6

Tags: checkout, shipping, payment-methods, paypal, billing

After upgrading my magento verison to 2.4.6. I am not able to place order due to payment method not working. For paypal it is giving error that internal error occured. For federal wire and other methods it is saying please provide email and it is redirecting to a page which is saying "AN error occured". Looking at the console i found that it is saying 500 "Not found" rest/default/V1/guest-carts/fIz7hCfhz1G5DskFWdcdXD9teebIzqBD/set-payment-information . I am not able to debug the issue. I think its related to shipping and billing address

Comment: check all log files in var/log/

Comment: Please use this patch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37242#issuecomment-1541797057 It is working fine.